# JPA error QuerySyntaxException: Player is not mapped [SELECT p FROM Player p]

Tags: postgresql, jpa, microprofile

I'm trying using JPA to do a simple get query inside eclipse microprofiles, this way:

Class Player:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "player")
public class Player {...
```

Main Class:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/hello2")
public class HelloWorld extends Application {





    @Path("/players")
    @GET
    public List<Player> getPlayers() {
        EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testMicroProfile").createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        List<Player> list  = null;
        transaction.begin();
        TypedQuery<Player> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Player p", Player.class);
        list = query.getResultList();
        transaction.commit();
        return list;
    }


}
```

And this is the file persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="testMicroProfile" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/microprofiledb"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="psw"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The name of the table in the database is `player`, but I've read in another answer on stackoverflow that I had to use the name of the class inside the query, so I've changed it in "Player", but doesn't work anyway. What's missing?

Comment: What server do you use? Eclipse MicroProfile doesn't contain JPA itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your entity class to *persistence.xml*:

```
<persistence-unit name="testMicroProfile">
    <class>my.test.Player</class>
```